# Unknown function 'exists'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a beginner.

I have two labels in my database; user, film. I have a relationship type called `[:WATCHLISTED]` between those two nodes. I want to get the usernames and film's names and whether they've added that film to their watchlist or not. Here's what I've written so far:

```
    MATCH (n),(f)
RETURN n.username AS username,f.name AS name, exists((n)-[:WATCHLISTED]->(f)) AS watchlisted
```

But I get this error:

```
     Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'exists' (line 2, column 47 (offset: 68))
"RETURN n.username AS username,f.name AS name, exists((n)-[:WATCHLISTED]->(f)) AS watchlist"
                                                       ^
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't see it. Thank you for you attention.

EDIT:
I wrote EXISTS() instead of exists() and it worked. I don't know why. Good day.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Neo4j Browser version: 3.1.14, Neo4j Server version: 3.4.1 (enterprise)

Comment: Your query is fine as far as I can tell. I've copied and pasted it in my browser (same browser and Neo4j version) and it executes without error. Any chance there are any odd characters in your query string?

Comment: I can't find anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you run an EXPLAIN of the query? Probably not if it's giving you syntax errors, but give it a try. Also see if you can run this via cypher-shell (it's in the bin directory of your neo4j installation)

Comment: I can't run explain, it gives the same error. But I'm not writing anything differently from this code here. I tried cypher-shell, it also gives the same error.

Comment: Hey, so I wrote EXISTS() instead of exists() and it worked.

Comment: That's very odd, cypher function names aren't case sensitive.

Comment: I was a bit frustrated, to be honest. Didn't expect that to be the problem. Thank you for your help. You've been a good support.

Comment: As previously mentioned, function names aren't case sensitive, so I'm still scratching my head on this one. Could you provide the OS you're using and its version? And if you're going through the Desktop app or the server installation? Since I can't replicate this on my system, seems like it could be OS specific?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174702/discussion-between-elif-sahin-and-inversefalcon).